# In unity3d, How can i add a new class file to my project using visual studio?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the visual studio in the project name i make right click then add then class.
The new created .cs file is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace
{
    class CUBE
    {
    }
}
```

First why it's not giving some namespace automatic ? I'm getting error. I can give my own namespace name but not sure why it's creating it like this.

I will want later to use this class in other cs file script i have.
I could also just a create a new script file in the editor but i wonder how to work with a class ? Or maybe i should just create a script file and working with it like a class ?

Comment: Within visual studio, you can make templates for things like this. You should also be able to see the project's structure in VS so that you can make new scripts in the proper places. I've never done it this way, but I don't see why you couldn't.

Comment: A namespace requires a name, just as a class does. So `namespace myrootfolderoflibrary.subfolder.myclasses` as an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*according to my observation/understanding.*

If you add any cs file directly in to visual studio(when using unity editory) it will create that file next to asset folder which is not correct. Every cs file that you want to utilized must be in asset folder.

And as you know, VS is a separate application so if you want to add a new class you should create it inside asset folder using the unity editor. And remember each script that inheriting from [Mono Behaviou](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html)r must match file and class name while for other classes(that are not inheriting from monobheviour-like in your case) you can change its file name but create it inside asset folder.

[image]